# MySql Stored Procedure doesn't return data when call from Asp.net Core Application

Tags: mysql, asp.net-core, stored-procedures, .net-core

I've created a Stored Procedure in MySQL. When I call that procedure with a parameter in MySQL Workbench, it gives some data when I call it with same parameter from my Asp.net Core Code, It doesn't return any row. Here is my code, Is there any problem in the code?

```
DBConnection context = HttpContext.RequestServices.GetService(typeof(DBConnection)) as DBConnection;
        using (var con =  context.getConnection())
        {
            string command = "PS19_CLIENTDATA_SELECT";

            con.Open();
            MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand(command,con);
            string id = User.FindFirstValue(ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@user_ID", id);
            cmd.CommandType = System.Data.CommandType.StoredProcedure;
            var reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
            while(reader.Read())
            {
                ClientDataViewModel tempModel = new ClientDataViewModel();
                tempModel.Filename = reader["FileName"].ToString();
                tempModel.userID = reader["userID"].ToString();
                tempModel.isDirectory = (bool)reader["isDirectory"];
                tempModel.remarks = reader["Remarks"].ToString();
                tempModel.userName = reader["UserName"].ToString();
                model.Add(tempModel);
            }
            con.Close();
        }
```

Comment: console your query which is gonna hit to the DB in application level. Then see what's wrong with. Even you could copy and paste it in workbench and see output.

Comment: How I can get the query?

Answer (score 0):

I think you have to use call to execute stored procedure.

e.g., string command = "call PS19_CLIENTDATA_SELECT('input1','input2',...)"

Comment: I tried following but didn't work :(
string command = "CALL PS19_CLIENTDATA_SELECT (@user_ID);";
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@user_ID", id);